# Import script in sub directory not working... Blender Add-On

Tags: python-3.x, import, blender, init

## I have a folder structure like this:

```
C: 
|_Blueprint
│   main.py
│
└───toolbox
        blueprint_tools.py
```

### When I run this code in Blender's scripting text page:

```
from toolbox.blueprint_tools import dimension, array, modify
```

### I get an error in the console

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "\main.py", line 20, in <module>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toolbox'
> Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
> ```

---

I swear, when I run this code (on other projects) outside of Blender this structure and code runs fine. But I get an error when running this script in Blender for testing out my Add-On.

*If I compile the Blueprint folder into a .zip and install it everything works fine.... ??
I'm lost, could anyone please help me.*

### If I run the code like this: (added a . before toolbox for CWD)

```
from .toolbox.blueprint_tools import dimension, array, modify
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "\main.py", line 20, in <module>
> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
> Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
> ```

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your error traces write `File \main.py ...` which means that Blender considers your `main.py` file to be in the root folder, knowing nothing about its real location in the file system hierarchy.

When you installed your structure as a zip file, you provided all necessary info to Blender.

---

*Addendum:*

Temporarily, during developing / debugging your add-on, you may add the *full path* (for finding your `toolbox.blueprint_tools` module)  to the `sys.path` variable.

There are 2 possibilities how to do it:

---

1. Insert into your `main.py` file these commands (use the path to *your* **parent** folder of your `toolbox` folder, of course):

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path += [r"C:\Users\Davi\Documents\Python\PARENT_of_toolbox"]
   ```

   **before** your statement

   ```
   from toolbox.blueprint_tools import dimension, array, modify
   ```

   command, or

---

2. Insert into your `main.py` file these commands (use the path to *your* `toolbox` folder, of course):

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path += [r"C:\Users\Davi\Documents\Python\PARENT_of_toolbox\toolbox"]
   ```

   **before** your **modified** statement

   ```
   from blueprint_tools import dimension, array, modify
   ```

Comment: Thank you, your answer makes perfect sense. But I guess the only thing left is how do I give Blender all the info it needs to run my script in Blender for testing purposes?

Comment: Use the zip file, as you already did. You may find more info about Blender specific questions in [Blender StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/). Maybe [this answer](Use the zip file, as you already did. You may find more info about Blender specific questions in [Blender StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/). Maybe [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/203926).

Comment: Thanks again, it's just horrible to have to compile a zip and install it just to see a small change I made to the add-on only to make a new change and have to uninstall recompile and try again... you see what I mean. This crazy thing works as a zip install but doesn't as a python.py file running inside Blenders script panel.

Comment: MarianD thank you so much. I'll give this a try tomorrow morning and report back. I appreciate your help.